# PHP date how to check the day of the week

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to create an scheduler task, so say I create a task due at

```
`6/24/2014` which is Tuesday the 4th week.
```

and I have today's date

```
`7/27/2014` which is Tuesday the 4th week also
```

How can I check in PHP so that if I check today is Tuesday the 4th week, create a new task based on previous task (I have a copy function, so the main question really is just the date part).

e.g:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($fromdatabasetheoriginaltaskdate);
$date2 = new DateTime($todaysdate);
```

Also, let's assume if the original task is on the 5th week, then it will count as the last week of the month which means, next month the task will be created on the last week of the month (regardless it's the 4th or 5th week).

Comment: You mean 7/29/2014 is tuesday and it is the 5th week.

Comment: just read the doc, evrything is in ...

Comment: @Samosa no, I mean if it's created on 6/24 which is the 4th week, then it should be created on the 4th week too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are just having trouble figuring out N in "this date is the Nth Tuesday of the month"...

If you do `DateTime::format("d");` you get back the number, in this case `24`.  Then you can divide by 7 and round up.

```
$date1 = new DateTime($a);
$date2 = new DateTime($b);
$days_in_a_week = 7;
$day1 = $date1->format("d");
$day2= $date2->format("d");
$which_week1 = ceil($day1/$days_in_a_week); //4
$which_week2 = ceil($day2/$days_in_a_week); //4
if ($date1->format("D") == $date2->format("D") && $which_week1 == $which_week2) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: this is pretty much what I need although I need to customize it a little bit. but $which_week1 and $which_week2, should be ceil instead of max. Fix it, and I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Shouldn't max input be an array if only 1 input is given ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want if a task is created 1st, 2nd, 3rd week of this month it should be replicated 1st, 2nd, 3rd week of next month. But if it was created Last week of this month it should be created last week of next month irrespective if this month it was 4th or 5th.

If so Try this :-

```
$date = "6/24/2014";
$strtotime = strtotime($date);


$array = array(1=>"first",2=>"second",3=>"third",4=>"fourth",5=>"fifth");

$current_month = date('n',$strtotime);
$day_num = date('d',$strtotime);
$day_word = date('l',$strtotime);
$next_month = date('F',strtotime('next month',$strtotime));
$next_week_month = date('n',strtotime('next '.$day_word, $strtotime));
$num_of_days = date('t',$strtotime);

$week = ceil($day_num/7);

$word = $array[$week];

if($next_week_month > $current_month){
    $word = 'last';
}

echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($word.' '.$day_word.' of '.$next_month.' 2014')); //Outputs 2014-07-29
```

Also this script checks if the current day is the last of this month. For example:-

6/24/2014 is the Last Tuesday but is 4th Week and there are 5 Weeks in June.